# How to clear sql statement

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I was trying to assign privileges in mySQL, using:

```
grant all privileges on db1.* to user1' with grant option;
```

this didn't work, so I am trying to clear the statement and return to 
"mysql>". I have tried /c and /q, but nothing seems to work. It keeps returning the to the next line ">". Please let me know how to fix this. 
Thanks

Comment: press ctrl+c....to exit program(assuming you are on windows)

Comment: Or typing another single quote to close the string might solve the problem.

Comment: Yup, I was missing a quote. Thanks